# Convert boolean values to false within braces

Tags: javascript

I have some boolean values held within braces. What would a function look like to toggle each one to false? I've tried `conf.column = !conf.column` but that just sets the whole thing to false, understandably, not each individual boolean.

```
conf.column = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: true,
  d: true,
  e: true
 };
```

Comment: Do you want to "*convert each one to false*" or do you want to toggle them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loop the object using `for..in` & change the value of the key

```js
let column = {
  a: true,
  b: true,
  c: true,
  d: true,
  e: true
};

for (let keys in column) {
  column[keys] = !column[keys]

}


console.log(column)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks, i'll mark it as the answer when it lets me!

Answer (score 3):

You can do a `forEach`

```
Object.keys(conf.column).forEach(c => conf.column[c] = false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just [loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) them:

```
for (const key in conf.column)
    conf.column[key] = !conf.column[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Object.keys(conf.column)
   .forEach(key => {
      conf.column[key] = !conf.column[key]
})
```

read about [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 1):

Non-mutating functional approach - construct a new object with the desired values and assign it to the original one.

```
conf.column = Object.keys(conf.column).reduce((result, key) => {
  result[key] = false;
  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Saying "non-mutating" and "assign it to" doesn't go well together…

Answer (score 0):

Take a look you want to update the keys and not the object.

```js
const conf = {}
conf.column = {
  a: true,
  b: true
}

Object.keys(conf.column).forEach((key) => conf.column[key] = !conf.column[key])

console.log(conf.column)
```

Answer (score 0):

Many possible solutions. But be careful if your object has other attributes type than Boolean don't forget to test it.

```
var myObject = {
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: true,
    d: undefined,
    e: null,
    f: "a string",
    g: 21
}

for (var attribut in myObject) {
    if (typeof(myObject[attribut]) === "boolean") {
        myObject[attribut] = !myObject[attribut];
    };
};
```